# Android 11: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground

Tags: java, android, service, notifications, android-notifications

Trying to start foreground service as per the code :

```
final Notification.Builder notificationBuilder;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
  final NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                    getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
  mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
  notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(mAppContext, CHANNEL_ID);
} else {
  notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(mAppContext);
}
final Notification notification = notificationBuilder
            .setContentTitle(mAppContext.getResources()
            .getString(R.string.initiate_partner_apps))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .build();
startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

But I am faced with the below error :

```
D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.my.package, PID: 8320
E AndroidRuntime: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2020)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7719)
E AndroidRuntime:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E AndroidRuntime:   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E AndroidRuntime:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

The above code didn't cause any issues in Android 8.1 but started seeing this in Android 11 only.

So far whatever I have seen online, the error message also lists a reason pointing out invalid channel Id. In my case not only is there no reason listed out but also I have been using the same constant `CHANNEL_ID` so I know I am not making that mistake.

I am not able to understand what could be the possible reason for this error

Answer (score 1):

What do you **realy** want to start? A foreground service or a notification (or both)?
If a foreground service, you can do this with an intent (and **not** a notification):

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
```

If you want to show a notification, then the line

```
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

is missing.